# Accumulative subscript/superscripts?

Tags: unicode, subscripts, superscripts, fun

With the objective of writing a textual aliasing package that would make it possible to write input that better approximates the output, I encountered the following problem: create a control sequence, say `\subscript` that behaves just like `_` except that it accumulate, i.e., `$a\subscript b \subscript c$` would be interpreted as `$a\subscript{bc}$`.

(Yes, I am aware of `unicode-math`. The purpose here is very different - not support of Unicode, but taking advantage of Unicode to write shorter and perhaps clearer input.)

Here is a minimal example which demonstrates the potential benefit.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{^2}   % ² 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B9}{^1}   % ¹ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1D62}{_i}   % ᵢ
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{207B}{^-}   % ⁻ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{207F}{^n}   % ⁿ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2080}{_0}   % ₀ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{208C}{_=}   % ₌ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2211}{\sum} % ∑ 

\begin{document}
\[
  ∑ᵢ₌₀ⁿ⁻¹ 2i+1 = n²
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: although there are some sub- and superscripts defined in unicode, they really shouldn't be used in math.  the unicode opinion (that is, the opinion of the unicode technical committee) is that such expressions require markup, which isn't the job of unicode.  see [unicode technical report #25, support for mathematics](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr25/), section 2.8.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: not really. This is not using Unicode for subscripts. It is using Unicode as aliases for the LaTeX markup language. With `\DeclarUnicodeCharacter`, the text processing system does not manipulate subscript Unicode characters. It manipulates markup commands which are generated by certain Unicode characters. 
Unicode-math, as I understand it, extends LaTeX to deal with many Unicode code points. The purpose here is different. LaTeX stays the same- you just apply some (almost) one-to-one aliasing.

Comment: what would you do if your sub/superscripts included greek letters, for example?  there will never be a full set of all possible  subs or sups.  also, how would you distinguish between first and second-order scripts?

Comment: The package is not intended to cover everything. In fact, and unlike `unicode-math`, it is intended to be minimal: cover as many as possible of the more common patterns, with as few as possible characters.Please look here for the rather small subset I have in mind: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/189PohjhFHpPc-AXyHjDVLFAaOSZoUZ5MOYv_QrYSq3s/edit?usp=sharing. (Macros, editors short cuts and scripts are auto generated) Currently used in all my writings. Just wanted to package it so that others could enjoy. I figured    cumulative sub/sups would make it a bit more useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can show you that it is possible. But using `csplain`, no LaTeX. I don't know what to do in LaTeX, because there is very complicated expansions when `[utf8]{inputenc}` is used.

```
\def\declchar#1#2{%
   \expandafter\mubyte\csname\string#2\endcsname#1\endmubyte
   \expandafter\def\csname\string#2\endcsname{#2}%
}
\mubytein=0
\declchar{²}{\mysupu 2}
\declchar{¹}{\mysupu 1}
\declchar{ᵢ}{\mysupd i}
\declchar{⁻}{\mysupu -}
\declchar{ⁿ}{\mysupu n}
\declchar{₀}{\mysupd 0}
\declchar{₌}{\mysupd =}
\declchar{∑}{\sum}
\mubytein=1

\def\mysuplist{}
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\mysupu#1{\addto\mysuplist{#1}\expandafter\futurelet
   \expandafter\next\expandafter\mysupuA}
\def\mysupuA{\ifx\next\mysupu \else ^{\mysuplist}\gdef\mysuplist{}\fi}
\def\mysupd#1{\addto\mysuplist{#1}\expandafter\futurelet
   \expandafter\next\expandafter\mysupdA}
\def\mysupdA{\ifx\next\mysupd \else _{\mysuplist}\gdef\mysuplist{}\fi}

$$
  ∑ᵢ₌₀ⁿ⁻¹ 2i+1 = n²
$$

\bye
```

**Edit** I thought about your comment, why LaTeX is more complicated. Because there are more expansion steps form active representation of the UTF-8 code to the contents declared in `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`. This means that you needs more `\expandafter`s. But I have a new idea. You can use the `` \rommannumeral-`\. `` trick which expands to nothing and does full expansion of the next token until space or unexpandable token occurs. And space is simply ingnored in math mode. So, there is a solution for LaTeX:

Declare:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{ \mysupu 2}   % ² 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B9}{ \mysupu 1}   % ¹ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1D62}{ \mysupd i}   % ᵢ
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{207B}{ \mysupu -}   % ⁻ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{207F}{ \mysupu n}   % ⁿ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2080}{ \mysupd 0}   % ₀ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{208C}{ \mysupd =}   % ₌ 
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2211}{\sum} % ∑
```

Note that there is an important space before `\mysupu` or `\mysupd`! And use my macros with the following modification:

```
\def\mysuplist{}
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\mysupu#1{\addto\mysuplist{#1}\expandafter\futurelet
   \expandafter\next\expandafter\mysupuA\romannumeral-`\.}
\def\mysupuA{\ifx\next\mysupu \else ^{\mysuplist}\gdef\mysuplist{}\fi}
\def\mysupd#1{\addto\mysuplist{#1}\expandafter\futurelet
   \expandafter\next\expandafter\mysupdA\romannumeral-`\.}
\def\mysupdA{\ifx\next\mysupd \else _{\mysuplist}\gdef\mysuplist{}\fi}
```

Note the `\romannumeral` trick.

Comment: Thanks Wipet. I am not sure I understand why your solution would not work for LaTeX.  Any tips?